# IntelliJ 9.0.3 Refused to Start Up on Mac OSX (Snow Leopoard)

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

My Intellij installation refused to start up on my macbook which is running snow leopard. In have reinstalled it and yet it refused to start up. i also set explicitly the Java_Home inside the .profile.

All it does is bounce and then fades away from my dock. Does any one have an idea what might be wrong.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try clearing the cache by deleting the directory `Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea90` in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue... I managed to start intellij idea though by browsing into the .app and running the idea.sh script in bin. You need to make sure JDK_HOME environmental variable is set to the location of the JDK, which for me was /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home.

EDIT: to clarify Elias's Answer, Deleting ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea90CE worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

This is the first result of a google search for this issue, so here's another solution for those with this problem (if the above answers don't work).

Check the permissions of your /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA XX.app/Contents/MacOS/idea executable. After upgrading to Mavericks, my executable permissions had been revoked and a chmod was required to allow me to run IntelliJ again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some problems with the built-in (default) java install.  You could try installing another java version perhaps?  Also, if you launch it from a terminal, you'll probably get a stacktrace or other error giving clues.